# sql query for modifications

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with data like this:

```
 EmpID   keyvaluePair
 1       1111-1-4.JPG
 2       4434-4-6.JPG 
 3       90899-4-3.JPG 
 4       8956-1-1.JPG 
 5       67827-9-5.JPG
```

Now I need to modify the above table data and insert data into another table.

Here the value is nothing but the end value in keyvaluepair column:

```
ID    Value
1     4
2     6
3     3
4     1
5     5
```

Hope my question is clear.

Can you help me out how to write a query to do the above operations

Thanks

Happysmile.

Comment: Will the right hand value in keyvaluepair always be a single digit?

Comment: I love any column with a name including a word like "Pair" in it, but especially one that appears to contain 3 elements.

Comment: @Damien: It depends on what you are counting. I can see exactly two hyphens in every row under `keyvaluePair`. Seems quite consistent with the name.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into SecondTable (ID, Value)
select EmpID, right(keyvaluePair,1) from FirstTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO NewTable(ID, Value)
SELECT EmpID, right(keyvaluePair,1) FROM OldTable
```

Comment: HEY  SORRY  the  requirment is like  the  above  one, i have  made  an change  in the values that is  stroed in keyvaluepair column.

Comment: i fially solved it   buy  using  cursor and an Table variable